On self-adjoint extensions and multiplicity of eigenvalues
I hope you can help me with the following question.
Let $B$ be a densely defined closed symmetric operator on a infinite-dimensional separable complex Hilbert space  $\mathcal{H}$ with deficiency indices equal to $n$. A triplet $\left( \mathbb{C}^{n},\Gamma_{1},\Gamma_{2}\right)$ where
$\Gamma_{i}:dom(B^{*})\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n}$ are linear mappings with $i=1,2$ is a boundary triplet to $B^{*}$ if:
**Satisfies the abstract Green identity, i. e.,
$$
\langle B^{*}x,y\rangle -\langle x,B^{*}y\rangle=\langle \Gamma_{2}x,\Gamma_{1}y\rangle_{\mathbb{C}^{n}} -\langle \Gamma_{1}x,\Gamma_{2}y\rangle_{\mathbb{C}^{n}}
$$
for each $x,y\in dom(B^{*})$
**The linear mapping $\Gamma=\Gamma_{1}\times\Gamma_{2}:D(B^{*})\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^{n}\bigoplus\mathbb{C}^{n}$ given by
$\Gamma x=\left( \Gamma_{1}x,\Gamma_{2}x\right) $ for each $x\in dom(H^{*})$ is surjective.
The Extensions Theorem by Boundary Triplets gives us a correspondence between self-adjoint extensions of $B$ and self-adjoint relations on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. If the relation is the graph of an self-adjoint operator with matrix representation $D$, we have that the associated self-adjoint extension of $B$, denoted by $A_{D}$, satisfies
$$
dom(A_{D})=Ker\;(\Gamma_{2}-D\Gamma_{1}).
$$
We also say that $B$ is completely non-selfadjoint if there is no subspace reducing $B$ such that the part of
$B$ in this subspace is self-adjoint.
Let $D_{m}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{H}_{n}$ (the set of symmetric matrices $n\times n$ on $\mathbb{C}$ endowed with the Euclidean norm) such that converges to $D\in\mathbb{H}_{n}$. Let $E_{m}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that converges to $E\in\mathbb{R}$ and $dimKer(A_{D_{m}}-E_{m}I)=n$.
The question is, does it happen that $dimKer(A_{D}-EI)=n$? I was able to demonstrate that E is an eigenvalue of $A_{D}$, however I was unable to determine its multiplicity. It is known that $dimKer(A_{D}-EI)\leqslant n$ if $B$ is completely non-selfadjoint. An alternative for the proof was take an orthonormal basis $\left\lbrace y^{i}_{m}\right\rbrace _{i=1}^{n}$ for each subspace $Ker(A_{D_{m}}-E_{m}I)$ and for the Banach-Alaoglu theorem for every $i=1,...,n$ there exists a subsequence of $y^{i}_{m}$ that weakly converges to $y^{i}$ in $\mathcal{H}$. It is expected that $\left\lbrace y^{i}\right\rbrace _{i=1}^{n} $ is an orthonormal basis for $Ker(A_{D}-EI)$. However, I have not been able to demonstrate that $\langle y^{i},y^{j}\rangle=0$ if $i\neq j$.
I would appreciate a good suggestion. Thank you for your time.
